# adding a variable into a function with colours?

Tags: php, html, sql

Hello i have a granit php function but would like to print my own text into it which is stored in side a variable and my own colours which are also stored in side variable

This is how the code looks be for i enter the variable

```
 gradient('FF0000', '0000FF', 'my test goes here');
```

Which works fine but now i want to put the variable

gradient($colour1,$colour2,$profile);

which is prining of the letter w  even thos if i just print of profile and the other 2 variable there all set... and none of them are just w

Here is were i get the colours...

```
    <?php 


    $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM profile_colurs WHERE username='{$profile}' ";
$result1 = mysql_query($sql1) or die(mysql_error());
$values1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1);


$co1= mysql_real_escape_string($values1['colour1']);
$colour1 = strip_tags($co1);
$co2= mysql_real_escape_string($values1['colour2']);
$colour2 = strip_tags($co2);
$co3= mysql_real_escape_string($values1['colour3']);
$colour3 = strip_tags($co3);


        include_once('functions/granit.php'); 

        gradient($colour1,$colour2,$profile); 


         ?>
```

All variable  print of perfect but has soon has i put it into the function im just getting "w"
What am i doing wrong ??

Comment: Test with just one variable at a time and see if you can get it to work. Like `gradient($colour1,'0000FF','my test')`. This way you can at least see which variable(s) are the culprit.

Comment: You don't run `mysql_real_escape_string` on data you got **FROM** the database.

Comment: Exactly why are you doing real_escape_string() on the data you're fetching? Unless you're going to use those values in another query, m_r_e_s() is utterly pointless and possibly harmful.

Answer (score 0):

First suggestion, don't use the `MySQL_*` function set. It is deprecated and its use is discouraged.

> Use of this extension is discouraged. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information. Alternatives to this function include:

Secondly, change your `mysql_fetch_array` to `mysql_fetch_assoc` if you only want the associative results (meaning column name as array index).

Lastly, do a `var_dump( get_defined_vars () );` and validate the data from the database to what you would expect. In your snippet of code, where is `$profile` set and what is it's value?